# Error while installing webrtcvad

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I end up with the following error while trying to install webrtcvad.

```
pip install webrtcvad

running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-2.7
copying webrtcvad.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
running build_ext
building '_webrtcvad' extension
error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for webrtcvad
Running setup.py clean for webrtcvad
```

Please help!

Update:

I tried to install by downloading the package from pypi.

[image]

I get the same error.

Comment: Is your pip up to date? I remember having a similar problem installing on windows because the setup.py was incorrect on windows. They have fixed it in more recent versions, I'd recommend trying to install from sources on pypi : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webrtcvad

Comment: Yes , pip is up to date - version :  9.0.1. And I tried to install by downloading from pypi. ( Updated my question with the snapshot). I get the same error.

Answer (score -1):

You can Install it (however it will take some data):
Download 
 Microsoft Visual Studio MSVC Version 140 (1GB approx) 
 Windows 10 Version 1809 (10.0.17763.0)(700-800 MB approx) from Windows 10 SDK Archive website or from Visual Studio installer.

 After downloading and Installing these 2 things, go where these 2 things are installed. For ex: In Case of MSVC 140 it would be, C:/Program files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0(you may have different version). You may see some folders inside.
Now go to search bar and search for rc.exe and add this folder into your environment variables. Now go to Windows 10 SDK folder : C:/Program files or Program files (x86)/Windows SKD kit something/10/10.0.17763.0 or anyfolder with 17763 in it.
Inside this folder (17763), look for ucrt folder and add this to env. variable.
Now install anaconda and set up your python.
And do :
pip install webrtcvad.
It may have installed correctly this time.
And make sure that :
wheel package is installed and updated.
setuptools package is updated.
pip is updated.

Comment: please organize your answer its hard to read